# Unable to install PyTorch - ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: windows, python, pip

I am trying to work with python zincbase and need to install pytorch on windows for that. When executing

```
pip install torch
```

I get an error saying

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\data-nobackup\development\im-099329- 
gremlintest\env\scripts\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\104172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5go0i_r_\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\104172\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-5go0i_r_\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\104172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bk0m_2ck' --python-tag cp36
   cwd: C:\Users\104172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5go0i_r_\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\104172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5go0i_r_\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
  description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
File "c:\data-nobackup\development\im-099329-gremlintest\env\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
  return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\data-nobackup\development\im-099329-gremlintest\env\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
  self.run_command('build')
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
  self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "c:\customsoftware\python3.6\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "C:\Users\104172\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-5go0i_r_\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
  from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
```

---

```
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
```

How can I install pytorch?

Comment: You won't be able to install PyTorch on windows via `pip`, as there are no prebuilt packages on PyPI for windows (and the one source dist `pip` finds is way too outdated). You should use Anaconda on Windows and install from PyTorch official channel.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply visit the PyTorch website at [pytorch.org](https://pytorch.org/)

Then go to the "Get started" page. You will see an interesting online tool in which you can select different options and it will provide a proper command to install "torch".

Just like the following picture:

[image]

As you can see with the above selection, the following command for torch installation would be the result:

```
pip3 install torch==1.3.1+cpu torchvision==0.4.2+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike other libraries, we can't just install PyTorch locally with pip install torch command.

Go to https://pytorch.org website and choose your machine and environment and it will provide you the command to run, like this -

`pip3 install torch===1.2.0 torchvision===0.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

### For Python 3.7 -

`pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
`pip3 install torchvision`